# Rails devise - endpoint which actually do confirm action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using devise for authentication process and now I want to setup confirmation account for given email (`:confirmable` module in devise). My app is an API app which connects with the front-end app (it's a mobile app in fact) using REST endpoints. I want to know which endpoint from the standard devise flow is responsible for sending email and which actually confirm accounts (to hook `confirm` button in email).

my routes:

```
root@83afeb8ffb71:/usr/src/app# rails routes | grep account
  new_account_confirmation GET    /api/v1/account/confirmation/new(.:format)                                               api/v1/account/confirmations#new {:format=>:json}
      account_confirmation GET    /api/v1/account/confirmation(.:format)                                                   api/v1/account/confirmations#show {:format=>:json}
                           POST   /api/v1/account/confirmation(.:format)                                                   api/v1/account/confirmations#create {:format=>:json}
```

I saw in the [docs](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/confirmations_controller.rb#L11) the email is trigger by `POST   /api/v1/account/confirmation` so which endpoint is doing some changes when user click `confirm` button from an email? I don't see any PUT endpoints in docs.

Answer (score 0):

1. Confirmation email sent on sign up action (by default), so you don't
   need to call `POST   /api/v1/account/confirmation`
2. You can't
   redirect user to `PUT POST DELETE PATCH` only to `GET`, so
   in email your application sent this url `GET    /api/v1/account/confirmation`, you can use deeplink on this endpoint and redirect user to app.

Comment: Ok but front-end dev needs to connect some endpoint with re-sent button if someone want to send confirmation email again. Regarding number 2 of your answear - `POST /api/v1/account/password` triggers `send_reset_password_instructions` in devise (by default) when user wants to reset their passwords - I want to have the same endpoint to trigger the confirmation process.

Comment: So, ```POST   /api/v1/account/confirmation``` trigger resend confirmation letter, you're right, but after that use need go to the ```GET    /api/v1/account/confirmation``` action with confirmation token and at this endpoint he is being confirmed